# RequireJS shim for script containing only a callback

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have an external API which provides a script file with javascript callback function in it. It assumes the function is implemented in my code.

eg a JS file with the following content:

```
aCallback({json:'stuff'});
```

I would like to wrap this in a requireJS module but am not too sure how to go about it.

I have tried the following shim:

```
define("my-wrapper", [], function () {
        return function(data){ console.log(data); }
    }
);
var require = {
    shim: {
        "my-wrapper": {exports: "aCallback"},
        "http://api.con/service": ["my-wrapper"]
    }
};

require(["http://api.con/service"], function (service) {});
```

but it says when it try's to load the service that `aCallback` is undefined. What have I got wrong? Is there a better way to wrap this kind of script?

Comment: So the service is expecting a global function called `aCallback`?

Comment: @SimonSmith its expecting a function called aCallback, im assuming if require loads it, it only needs to be in the local namespace. Is this not correct? Its a bit of a weird way of providing data imo but I have no control over the api.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try requiring the callback as a dependency instead of using `shim` so that it does exist in the same scope.

```
require(["http://api.con/service", "my-wrapper"], function (service, aCallback) {

});
```

It does depend on how the service expects to consume the callback though.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work, I get the same error `aCallback is not defined` the actual service is very simple, its just a js file containing a single line `aCallback({json:'stuff'});` which executes when its loaded